# Python program to print student grade from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

So I want to write a program that asks the user for two files, one of which contains the student's student number, first and last name and the other contains also the student's student number and the points they got from exercises 1-7. The program should print the student's first and last name and the sum of the points. What I have so far:

```
info = input("File with student info: ")
ex = input("File with exercise points: ")

names = {}

with open(f"{info}") as f:
for row in f:
    p = row.split(';')
    if p[0] == "student number":
        continue
    names[p[0]] = p[1] + " " + p[2]

exercises = {}

with open(f"{ex}") as f:
for row in f:
    p = row.split(';')
    if p[0] == "student number":
        continue
    exercises[p[0]] = int(p[1]) +int(p[2]) +int(p[3]) +int(p[4]) +int(p[5]) +int(p[6]) +int(p[7])


for studentnumber, name in names.items():
if studentnumber in exercises:
    e = exercises[studentnumber]
    print(f"{name} {e}")
```

This prints

```
will williams
 21
dave davis
 35
```

But I would want it to print the points on the same line as the names. Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: Try `print(f"{name} {e}")` --> `print(f"{name.strip()} {e}")`

Comment: Either `name` ends in a newline `\n` or `e` begins with one

Comment: Better yet, instead of calling `.strip()` when printing call it when processing data: `p = row.split(';')`  --> `p = row.strip().split(';')` Additionally you can make summing points be more concise and pythonic by changing it to `exercises[p[0]] = sum(map(int, p[1:8]))` but that may be a little more advanced.